# Not able to display JUnit tests result in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a piece of Jenkins pipeline code in which I am trying to run JUnit on my angular code.

If the unit tests fail, Jenkins has to stop the pipeline.
It's working except I am not able to see "Latest test Result" and "Test Result Trend"

I am using Jenkins 2.19.1, Jenkins Pipeline 2.4 and Junit 1.19. Here is the pipeline code:

```
{
        sh("npm install -g gulp bower")
        sh("npm install")
        sh("bower install")    
        try {
            sh("gulp test")
        } catch (err) {
            step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/reports/junit/*.xml', healthScaleFactor: 1.0])
            junit '**/reports/junit/*.xml'
            if (currentBuild.result == 'UNSTABLE')
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
            throw err
        }
    }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 31):

If you use declarative pipeline, you can do something like:

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
     stage('Build and Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'build here...'
            sh 'run tests here if you like ...'
        }
     }
   }
   post {
      always {
        junit '**/reports/junit/*.xml'
      }
   } 
}
```

This could also work with html publishing or anything, no need for finally/catch etc. it will always archive the results.

See https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline for more.

If you have a *clean* target that results in no test output:

```
  post {
    always {
      junit(
        allowEmptyResults: true,
        testResults: '**/test-reports/*.xml'
      )
    }
```

Comment: I have this in my Jenkinsfile and it puts junit info in for each build. Is there a way to get summaries/trends from this data?

Comment: @nroose The job contains then a diagram with the test results trends.

Comment: @michael-neale Thanks for the `allowEmptyResults` hint!

Comment: Should be `'**/test-results/test/*.xml'`

Answer (score 7):

Jenkins Pipeline step for publishing JUnit-style test results produced by a **Gradle build**:

```
  stage('Publish test results') {
      steps {
          junit '**/test-results/test/*.xml'
      }
  }
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore, Unknown stage section "junit"

Comment: There is probably a specific junit plugin required to enable the `junit` keyword to work in the DSL - https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/junit/#-junit-archive-junit-formatted-test-results

Answer (score 4):

I think the way I was trying to do previous was wrong.I have changed my code like below and it works :

```
{
        sh("npm install -g gulp bower")
        sh("npm install")
        sh("bower install")
        try {
            sh("gulp test")
        } catch (err) {
            if (currentBuild.result == 'UNSTABLE')
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
            throw err
        } finally {
            step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/reports/junit/*.xml', healthScaleFactor: 1.0])
            publishHTML (target: [
                    allowMissing: false,
                    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
                    keepAll: true,
                    reportDir: 'coverage',
                    reportFiles: 'index.html',
                    reportName: "Junit Report"
            ])
        }
    }
```

Comment: The PublishHTML for coverage data is not the same thing as publishing JUnit results.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are generating the JUnit reports only when the tests fail, which is probably not what you want. Instead use `finally` to always publish the tests:

```
   {
        sh("npm install -g gulp bower")
        sh("npm install")
        sh("bower install")    
        try {
            sh("gulp test")
        } finally {
            step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/reports/junit/*.xml', healthScaleFactor: 1.0])
            junit '**/reports/junit/*.xml'
        }
    }
```

I prefer to use `finally` over having it in `post`, because this way, things are together that belong together.