# Jenkins Pipeline and SonarQube setup

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I'm having some trouble setting up SonarQube using Maven on a Jenkins Pipeline.

My pipeline pulls the git repo into the directory created for it and it goes through the rest of the steps successfully but I don't see the test results on SonarQube nor any output that tests are being ran.

Here is my code set up on the pipeline:

```
node('master'){

  stage('Git Clone') {
    dir('my-git-dir'){
    git branch: '$GIT_BRANCH'
      git url: '$GIT_REPO'
      credentialsId: '11111111-111-1111-1111-111111111111'
   }
  }

  stage('build & SonarQube Scan') {
      MVN="/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.3.9/bin/mvn"
      echo "running clean verify sonar"
      "$MVN clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://111.11.1.111:9000 -Dsonar.java.binaries=/etc/sonarqube"
      echo "running clean install"
      "$MVN clean install deploy -DskipTests"
  }
}
```

The command runs just fine on a free style project:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
MVN="/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.3.9/bin/mvn"
$MVN clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://111.11.1.111:9000 -Dsonar.java.binaries=/etc/sonarqube
$MVN clean install deploy -DskipTests
```

It also has an "Invoke top-level Maven targets"
Maven Version:

```
Maven 3.3.9
```

Goals:

```
test
-fn
```

**Edit: Working Script**

```
  stage('SonarQube analysis') {
     dir("$gitRepo"){
    withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
      sh "pwd"
      MVN="/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.3.9/bin/mvn"
      echo "Running JaCoCO stuff"
      sh "$MVN clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false"
      echo "running clean verify"
      sh "$MVN clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://111.11.1.111:9000" //-Dsonar.java.binaries=/etc/sonarqube"
      echo "running clean install deploy"
      sh "$MVN clean install deploy -DskipTests"
}
```

P.S I am trying to create a job that you can select a repo and branch to pull from, create/use a file in that workspace to run SonarQube on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question demonstrates several misunderstandings.

First, SonarQube analysis will not execute your tests for you; you need to fire that off yourself. As noted [in the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin) the command for that would be something like

```
$MVN clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false
```

followed by

```
$MVN sonar:sonar -sonar.host.url=http://111.11.1.111:9000
```

Note that I've left off the `-Dsonar.java.binaries=/etc/sonarqube` parameter you used. That's because

- This is the path to the compiled classes of your project. They *should not* be in `/etc/sonarqube`. (Move them if they are.)
- Maven analysis already knows where your binaries are so you don't need to provide the path unless your build is configured to put them somewhere strange.

Comment: Hi Ann, I am working off what the previous predecessor left off with but I appreciate the guidance. I'd like to start with the first command, I got this back on an error from an old freestyle project: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin would this replace the code after "clean" and before "-Dmaven..."?

Comment: @Lgalan90 I'm not a Mavenista. You should post a new question. That said, I don't think so. And if my answer helped you on this question, you should consider accepting it.

Comment: Hi again Ann, looks like this did the trick! However, would you happen to know why I am not able to view the "Coverage"? On the SonarQube Dashboard it shows 0.0% and 3 Unit tests.

Comment: @Lgalan90 are you firing off the unit tests before you run the analysis?

Comment: Please view my working script above, would I need to add a JUnit script before this stage or a post build script like in this article? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230668/not-able-to-display-junit-test-result-in-jenkins-pipeline
I also came across this article but wasn't sure how to handle the property changes(whether it was supposed to be changed on the repo's pom file or on the sonarqube properties file):
https://www.unicoda.com/?p=1798